# What is newer technologies in .NET for MSMQ

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, msmq

One of my customer needs a queue solution to log errors and then insert them into a database, however MSMQ seems very old, and they dont want to use any cloud services like Azure.

What are the newer platform or technologies regarding queues that I can create and send messages with .net?

Comment: 6.5k rep and you *still* don't know that this question is off topic?

Comment: and I got an answer

Comment: On a downvoted and closed question, congratulations...

Comment: does it affect? no it doesnt! congrats! I got what I needed. have a nice life.

Comment: Yes it does, it pollutes the site with questions that are off topic. With 13.5 million questions here, it's important for the experienced members to try and keep it clean. You're abusing the system by not doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at RabbitMQ. There is a simplification framework EasyNetQ on nuget to make it easier.

Comment: thank you, you are really helpful.! not as the moderators.